# CABaseAnimation Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, core-animation

I used `CABaseAnimation` to create layer's animation,and set `CABaseAnimation`'s delegate to `viewController`, here is code:

```
let flyRight = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
    flyRight.delegate = self
    flyRight.toValue = view.bounds.size.width/2
    flyRight.fromValue = -view.bounds.size.width/2
    flyRight.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth
    flyRight.duration = 0.5

    flyRight.setValue(heading.layer, forKey: "heading")
    heading.layer.addAnimation(flyRight, forKey: nil)

    flyRight.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.3
    flyRight.setValue(username.layer, forKey: "username")
    username.layer.addAnimation(flyRight, forKey: nil)

    username.layer.position.x = view.bounds.size.width/2

    flyRight.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.4
    flyRight.setValue(password.layer, forKey: "password")
    password.layer.addAnimation(flyRight, forKey: nil)
    password.layer.position.x = view.bounds.size.width/2
```

the delegate `animationDidStop` method code is as follows:

```
 override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    print(anim)
    if let layer = anim.valueForKey("heading") as? CALayer {
        anim.setValue(nil, forKey: "heading")
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        animation.fromValue = 1.0
        animation.toValue = 1.5
        animation.duration = 1.0
        layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
        print("heading layer animation did stop")
        }
    }
```

but in the delegate method I found that the console prints three times "heading layer animation did stop", here is the print line in console:

```
<CABasicAnimation: 0x7fbe13096b10>
heading layer animation did stop
<CABasicAnimation: 0x7fbe13020bf0>
heading layer animation did stop
<CABasicAnimation: 0x7fbe13096c80>
heading layer animation did stop
```

I'm very confused as to why the print method executed three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code says (in essence):

```
flyRight.delegate = self
flyRight.setValue(heading.layer, forKey: "heading")
heading.layer.addAnimation(flyRight, forKey: nil)
username.layer.addAnimation(flyRight, forKey: nil)
password.layer.addAnimation(flyRight, forKey: nil)
```

So you are adding this animation to three different layers. Before you did that, you set its `"heading"` key to `heading.layer`, and you set the animation's `delegate` to `self`. Thus, we have three layers running an animation where `delegate` is `self` and where the `"heading"` key is `heading.layer`.

So now we come to your `animationDidStop` handler:

```
override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    if let layer = anim.valueForKey("heading") as? CALayer {
        print(/*...*/)
    }
}
```

So all three animations end up calling the `animationDidStop` handler, and in all three animations the `if let layer` test *passes*; all three of them do indeed have a key `"heading"` which is a CALayer. Hence, all three times you see the printout. It's obvious.

(Indeed, the only thing that is *not* obvious is *why you are surprised*. The only explanation I can think of is that you don't realize that `addAnimation:forKey:` adds a *copy* of the animation. That is something that some people do not realize. But it is hard to see why not realizing that would cause your surprise in this particular situation.)

Comment: Thank u very much! The key question is addAnimation:forKey: adds a copy of the animation,